# why is my mongoose findOne query returning more than one result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

i'm setting up a route to return a specific thing out of collection of things using findOne and the thing object id as the parameter. why is the result not returning only one matched thing?

i have tried findOne with the id as parameter

Here is the thing schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const thingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
title: { type: String, required: true },
description: { type: String, required: true },
imageUrl: { type: String, required: true },
userId: { type: String, required: true },
price: { type: Number, required: true }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Thing", thingSchema);
```

find thing route

```
  app.get("/api/stuff/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  Thing.findOne({
    _id: req.params.id
  })
    .then(thing => {
      res.status(200).json(thing);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(404).json({
        error: error
      });
    });
});
```

i expected the result of `/api/stuff/:5d9834968e23a32580a1751b` to be:

```
 {
        "_id": "5d9834968e23a32580a1751b",
        "title": "tecno camon 8",
        "description": "quality condition",
        "imageUrl": "https://i0.wp.com/www.techslize.com/wp-content    /uploads/2017/02/Tecno-camon-c8-black.png?resize=407%2C450&ssl=1",
        "price": 3000,
        "userId": "userID40282382",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

but the actual result is the whole thing collection.

Comment: I'm unsure why you are getting the "entire thing collection" as it just sounds like madness to me, however you have one issue that seems clear, you need to cast the `req.params.id` to be of mongoose ObjectID type for your query to work: `new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)`

Comment: Tried it but still the same result

Comment: I think theres something else going on, how are you debugging this route? are you sure this is the route your using? `findOne` returns an object not an array, this is a HUGE red flag that something is not working the way you intended.

Comment: @tomslabbaert i tried this and got the same thing collection:

  ` app.get("/api/stuff/:id",(req, res, next)=>` `{res.status(200).json(thing);});`

Comment: Are you debugging serverside or just looking at the response? any chance you have an other route thats being matched?

Comment: Thanks, really appreciates. There is an app.use   "/api/stuff"  but is it possible to have them both

Answer (score 0):

`req.params` comes from path segments of the URL that match a parameter in the route definition such a `/api/stuff/:id`. So, with a route using that designation and a URL such as `/api/stuff/5d9834968e23a32580a1751b`, then `_id: req.params.id`.

delete `:` from url `/api/stuff/:5d9834968e23a32580a1751b` and send with this url `/api/stuff/5d9834968e23a32580a1751b`